# Is an Acera cassette compatible with an 8-speed Deore rear derailleur?

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, derailleur, cassette, compatibility

Is this Shimano [Acera 8-speed cassette and chain](http://www.woollyhatshop.com/Chain-and-Cassette-Deals/Chain-amp-Cassette-Deals-8-Speed/Shimano-Acera-8-Speed-Cassette-11/32-CSHG418132-HG40-Chain-Combo-Deal/prod_4994.html) compatible with a Shimano Deore 8-speed rear derailleur on my mountain bike?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Acera 8-speed cassette that you link to should be compatible with an 8-speed Deore deailleur and shifters. The main compatibility issue is the spacing of sprockets, which changes with the number of sprockets and can vary between manufacturers. This [cassette spacing cribsheet](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-spacing.html) details the spacing for 8-speed Shimano cassettes, which should be the same for both Deore and Acera.

Edit: I should also mention that a cassette with a large maximum sprocket could be incompatible with some derailleurs, but this Acera cassette has a maximum sprocket size that is typical for a mountain bike.

Comment: just noticed the chain rings are IG, would the linked chain which is HG still work or not?

also thanks amcnabb.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't dealt with this personally, but it sounds like a HG chain can cause problems with an IG chainring (but sometimes it works). I guess it might be risky.